# Ben Franklin effect: mkay, what about help vampires?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, behavioral-economics, social-cognition

Is the [Ben Franklin effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_Franklin_effect) as uncontroversial as wikipedia makes it to be? It states that once we grant someone a favor we're even more inclined to grant them subsequent favors. As far as I can tell from Wikipedia the effect was experimentally tested (under rigorous conditions) maybe 3 times. If the effect always holds, how comes we (eventually) dislike [help vampires](http://www.skidmore.edu/~pdwyer/e/eoc/help_vampire.htm)? Is there a liking curve that goes up and then down with the number of favors?